# WordPress; update and store session variable using jquery and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am fairly new to WordPress and am having some issues that I can't solve on my own.

My goal is to update the session variable with the input the user entered in a textbox.

I then want to store the updated session variable to a text file.

I am using jquery and ajax. My code is not working. Any help would be great. Thanks.

I will do my best to explain my code. 
I will be happy to add additional information if I am not clear.

The form contains the following code:

```
<input type="text" id="question_in" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Add" />
```

My wordpress header.php contains the following:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery('#btn').click(function() {    
  var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';  
  updateSession();
});

function updateSession(){
 alert ("in updateSession!"); //for testing this displays
 var new_question = $("#question_in").val();    alert ("input is "+new_question); // for testing this works 

// This does the ajax request
$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url: "write-test.php",  
   data: "question=" + new_question,   
   success:function(){
    alert ("in success!");  //this displays
    },
    error: function(errorThrown){
        alert ("There is an error!");
    }
});    
}
</script>
```

Here is the code for  write-test.php

```
<?php
  session_start(); 
  if(isset($_POST['question'])) {

  $theQuestion = $_POST['question'];

  $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
  fwrite($myfile, $theQuestion);
  fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: You are submitting the form via `POST` so you should be reading from `$_POST` not `$_SESSION` in your `write-test.php`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply; I edited write-test.php to $_POST and the file is still not created. Any other insights?

Comment: Is `write-page.php` being called? Do you have a database connection setup (`mysql_real_escape_string()` requires a database connection)? What does your error log say?

Comment: I am not sure if it is being called. How can I tell? I took out the mysql_real_escape_string() call. It's a good idea to check the error log, I searched but could not find it. Where is it located?

Comment: The web developer part of your browser should be able to tell you if the call to `write-page.php` is successful or not. The log locations will depend on your OS and setup, typically on Linux its `/var/log/`

Comment: I did a search for error_log and could not locate it. I am running WAMP on windows 8.1 and testing the code on both firefox and IE. Is there another way I could check if write-page.php is being called?

Comment: I have tried a lot of variation but can still not get this to work. Any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The correct way to handle this is to use WP's admin-ajax.php file, instead of your own. See this Codex page:

http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side

Instead of putting the code in a custom php page, just put it in your functions.php file.
```